# Free Product on 3 Groups confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

This is a very basic question: How can the free product on three groups, say $G:=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ be a group? For example, let $a,b,c$ be the generators for the three copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ respectively, so $g:=abc\in G$.

Now, as I understand it, the group operation is concatenation followed by reduction, where we are allowed to delete the neutral element and multiply elements in the same group.

But now, consider $g^2=(abc)\cdot (abc)=abcabc$

Is this an element of $G$? It's my understanding that elements of $G$ have the form $g_1g_2g_3$ where $g_1\in \mathbb{Z}_a$, $g_2\in\mathbb{Z}_b$ and $g_3\in\mathbb{Z}_c$ (I'm denoting $\mathbb{Z}_\alpha$ as the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $\alpha$).

Can someone clear this up?

Comment: Elements of $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ are words in $a$ and $b$, so things like $ababbababaa$ are allowed, though they aren't "in order."

Comment: Your understanding that "elements of $G$ have the form $g_1g_2g_3$" is wrong. Perhaps you are confusing the free product with the direct product.

Comment: @runway44 can you elaborate? What form do elements of $G$ take, then, if not what I gave?

Comment: The group operation is concatenation. So, the form the elements of the free product take is whatever you can make by concatenating elements from the different free factors. As Randall points out, these are "words" formed using group elements as "letters" (modulo reduction, as you say).

Comment: $abcabc$ is a perfectly well valid element of $G$. You can only reduce when two elements of the same group occur one after another, but you cannot swap two elements of distinct groups in order to carry a word into the form $g_1g_2g_3$

Comment: Oh, so the elements actually have the form (after reduction) $g_1g_2g_3g_1'g_2'g_3'...$ and so on? taking $g_1,g_1'\in G_1$ etc

Comment: In your understanding, even the free product of *two* groups wouldn't make sense, since taking $a$ in the first group and $b$ in the second group would give you things like $abab$ that cannot be written as simply something in the first group times something in the second group.

Comment: They need not be in order. You could have $g_3g_1g_2g'_3$, etc. It is any finite concatenation of elements, no two consecutive ones from the same free factor, none trivial (unless you are taking the empty word).

Comment: Oh, I see! So really the only thing that defines them is that in a reduced (non-empty) word, each element is apart of a different group?

Comment: As long as consecutive "letters" aren't in the same group, you are good. For instance, say we took the reduced word $abc \in G$ and multiplied it by $cba \in G$. Concatenation alone gives $abccba$ but this is not in $G$ since both of the consecutive $c$'s belong to the group $\mathbb{Z}$ with $c$ as its generator. However, if instead we "reduced" the word to obtain $abc^2ba$, then that *would* be an element of $G$ since now $c^2$ is its own "letter" in the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's my understanding that elements of $G$ have the form $g_1 g_2 g_3$ where $g_1 ∈ ℤ_a$, $g_2 ∈ ℤ_b$ and $g_3 ∈ ℤ_c$ […].

No, this is wrong.

Let $G_1, \dotsc, G_n$ be groups.

- By a *word* in $G_1, \dotsc, G_n$ we mean a tuple $( (g_1, i_1), \dotsc, (g_ℓ, i_ℓ))$ with $ℓ ≥ 0$ and $(g_j, i_j)$ contained in $G_{i_j}$ for every position $j = 1, \dotsc, ℓ$.
  The number $ℓ$ is the length of this word.

Let us denote the set of all such words by $W$.

- We say that a word $( (g_1, i_1), \dotsc, (g_ℓ, i_ℓ) )$ is *reduced* if

  - $i_j ≠ i_{j + 1}$ for every $j = 1, \dotsc, ℓ - 1$, and
  - $g_{i_j}$ is not the neutral element of $G_{i_j}$ for every $j = 1, \dotsc, n$.

Let us denote the set of reduced words by $W_{\mathrm{red}}$.

As you already mentioned in your question, every words $w = ( (g_1, i_1), \dotsc, (g_ℓ, i_ℓ) )$ can be transformed into a reduced word by repeatedly applying the following two reduction rules:

1. If $i_j = i_{j + 1}$ for some position $j$, then replace $w$ by
   $$
     w' = ( (g_1, i_1), \dotsc, (g_{j-1}, i_{j-1}), \, (g_j g_{j + 1}, i_j), \, (g_{j+2}, i_{j + 2}), \dotsc, (g_ℓ, i_ℓ) ) \,.
   $$
2. If at some position $j$ the element $g_j$ is the neutral element of $G_{i_j}$, then replace $w$ by
   $$
     w' = ( (g_1, i_1), \dotsc, (g_{j-1}, i_{j-1}), (g_{j+2}, i_{j + 2}), \dotsc, (g_ℓ, i_ℓ) ) \,.
   $$

Starting with any word $w$, we get in this way a sequence of words
$$
  w \to w' \to w'' \to \dotsb
$$
until we arrive at a reduced word.
(This sequence must terminate, since each of the two reduction rules reduces the length by $1$.)
We have thus a reduction map
$$
  W \to W_{\mathrm{red}} \,.
$$
As you already explained in your post, we can now form the group $G_1 * \dotsb * G_n$ as follows:

- The underlying set of $G_1 * \dotsb * G_n$ is the set of reduced words $W_{\mathrm{red}}$.
- The multiplication of two reduced words is given by first concatenating them, and then reducing the resulting word.

The elements of $G_1 * \dotsb * G_n$ are typically not written as words $( (g_1, i_l), \dotsc, (g_ℓ, i_ℓ) )$, but as products $g_1 \dotsm g_ℓ$.
However, we must keep in the back of your minds that each factor $g_j$ in this product ‘remembers’ to which index $i_j$ it belongs.

In your example $G_1 = ℤ_a$, $G_2 = ℤ_b$, $G_3 =  ℤ_c$ we have, for example, the word
$$
  b^2 a c^{-1} a^2 b c^3
  =
  ((b^2, 2), (a, 1), (c^{-1}, 3), (a^2, 1), (b, 2), (c^3, 3))
$$
of length $6$.
This word is reduced, and therefore an element of $ℤ_a * ℤ_b * ℤ_c$.
It is the product of the two elements $b^2 a c^{-1}$ and $a^2 b c^3$, as well as the product of the three elements $b^2 a$, $c^{-1} a^2$ and $b c^3$.

---

It should be pointed out that the construction of $G_1 * \dotsb * G_n$ via reduced words is somewhat bad. We can instead do the following:

- We can turn $W$, the set of all words, into a monoid via concatenation.
  The neutral element of $W$ is given by the empty word.

The monoid $W$ is very much not a group:
no element of $W$ except for the neutral element has an inverse, since the concatenation of two words is only empty if both words were empty to begin with.

- Let $∼$ be the equivalence relation on $W$ generated by $w ∼ w'$ whenever $w'$ results from $w$ by one of the two reduction rules.
  This equivalence relation is compatible with the monoid structure of $W$:
  if $w_1 ∼ w'_1$ and $w_2 ∼ w'_2$, then also $w_1 w_2 ∼ w'_1 w'_2$.
  (In other words, the equivalence relation $∼$ is a congruence relation on $W$.)
  It follows that the monoid structure on $W$ descends to a monoid structure on the quotient set $W / {∼}$.
- The quotient $W / {∼}$ is not only a monoid, but a group:
  the inverse of an equivalence class $[((g_1, i_1), \dotsc, (g_ℓ, i_ℓ))]$ is given by $[((g_ℓ^{-1}, i_ℓ), \dotsc, (g_1^{-1}, i_1))]$.

We can now construct the free product $G_1 * \dotsb * G_n$ as the quotient $W / {∼}$.

The construction of the free product via reduced words uses the fact that $W_{\mathrm{red}}$ is a set of representatives for the equivalence relation $∼$.
This allows one to identity $W / {∼}$ with $W_{\mathrm{red}}$.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful!!